# Carousel View getting The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am getting error this error for while setting ItemsSource dataCollection for CarouselView.  This is not frequently happening...It happens on when 2-3 times I am coming back to page.
here is my code.

///this is in my VM

```
 public ObservableCollection<Data> dataCollection { get; set; }
```

///This is my UI

```
 new Grid()
                    {
                        ColumnDefinitions =
                            {
                                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                            },
                        ColumnSpacing=0,
                        RowSpacing=0,
                        Children =
                        {
                                new CarouselView
                                {
                                    HeightRequest=126,
                                    IndicatorView=_indicatorView,
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility= ScrollBarVisibility.Never,
                                    ItemsLayout = new LinearItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Horizontal)
                                    {
                                    ItemSpacing=0,
                                    SnapPointsType = SnapPointsType.MandatorySingle,
                                    SnapPointsAlignment = SnapPointsAlignment.Start
                                    },
                                    ItemTemplate=new DataTemplate(() =>
                                    {
                                        var rootstack=new StackLayout
                                        {
                                            HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                                            VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                                            Spacing=0,
                                            Orientation=StackOrientation.Vertical,
                                            Padding=new Thickness(48,10,48,13),
                                            Children=
                                            {
                                                new CustomLabel
                                                {
                                                    HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start,
                                                    VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start,

                                                }.Bind(CustomLabel.TextProperty,nameof(Data.name)),

                                                new CustomLabel
                                                {
                                                    HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start,
                                                    Style= CoreStyles.BODY_2_TIGHT,
                                                    MaxLines=2

                                                }.Bind(CustomLabel.TextProperty,nameof(Data.address)),

                                                new Button
                                                    {
                                                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                                                    IsEnabled = true,
                                                    }.Bind(Button, nameof(Data.call))
                                                    .Assign(out(callbtn)),
                                            }
                                        };
                                        return rootstack;
                                    })
                                }.Bind(CarouselView.ItemsSourceProperty,nameof(ViewModel.dataList))
                                .Assign(out(_carouselView))
                                .ColumnSpan(3),

                                                       }
                    }
```

Comment: if you are coming **back** to an existing page do you really need to execute this code again?

Comment: What is the error message? How do you do the  coming back operation?

Comment: @wendy-zang- await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageName(dataItem)) using this code I am navigating to this page... I am getting this error - The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Comment: @Jason Yes I have to execute this code this is content.cs page where in code behind I am rendering my UI

Comment: Its not clear from the posted code what the problem is. Some questions: 1) "I am coming back to page" - Does this mean "navigating back" to the page that was previously shown? 2) That UI code `new Grid()`: is it in (or called by) your view's constructor? 3) Show the complete method that contains that UI code.  I don't understand how it is put on the page. 4) Add to question the code that builds a new dataCollection, then sets `dataCollection = ...`.

Comment: 5) The UI has `Bind(CarouselView.ItemsSourceProperty,nameof(ViewModel.dataList)`. You show in the VM `dataCollection`. In your actual code, are `dataList` and `dataCollection` both the same name, instead of different names?

Comment: Disregard (1) - I see your comment re `PushASync`. 6) Add to question, code that shows `dataItem` being used. Anyone reading the question needs to be able to read through the code, see all the steps that create this UI. What you've shown leaves out some steps; it is not clear what is happening in the code.

Comment: 7) Various erors could occur if a change to `dataCollection` is done on a thread that is not the UI thread.

Comment: Thank You everyone for spending valuable time on this...I am able to fix this issue. In my code view model for this view was using single instance....I disposed my view model whenever I am going back from the current page.

Comment: In my case I found out that the crash is caused by the **IndicatorView**. It only happens when a template is assigned to to the **IndicatorTemplate**.
The crash does not occure in iOS though.